# Reentrantlock in openmp

Tags: c++, locking, openmp

I heard about Reentrantlock recently which are available in Java. But I was trying to implement parallel data structures like priority queues using openmp and C++.

I was curious to know whether a similar equivalent exists in openmp and C++ or whether it can be implemented using pthreads? If there exists such an equivalent, please tell how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the description of omp_nest_lock on page 270 (PDF page 279) in the [OpenMP 4.5 standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf).

A meta-question is "Why are you doing this?" 
Why aren't you simply using something like [TBB's Concurrent Priority Queue](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_priority_queue_cls.html)?
Do you need to be using OpenMP for other reasons?
Is this is for your own education?
If not, then TBB might be a simpler approach (it is now Apache Licensed).

(FWIW I work for Intel, who wrote TBB, but I work on OpenMP, not TBB :-))

Comment: I am doing lab project on Parallel data structures where the implementations should be done in openmp. I am trying to implement the lock based skip list method mentioned in book "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming - Maurice Herlihy & Nir Shavit" (pages 352 - 360). This required me to implement reentrantlocks. Thanks for giving link to already implemented library. But to get an idea about how the things are going on and trying to get an experience on writing parallel algorithms and data structures, I was trying to do the same.

Comment: Can you elaborate this statement a bit more (Pg 272 from the above book) : "The use of the same OpenMP lock in different contention groups results in unspecified behavior."

Comment: Since you have already stated that this is an educational project, I'm merely going to tell you to look up the definition of a "contention group" in the standard :-)  (A big part of learning is learning how to learn !)